# Get a single element in the List

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I took data from excel. and stored in the Lists. then
I want to get a single element in the `List`
my problem in the main method first loop it takes one List details. In second loop I want one element of that List
for examples `[OS1, 10.23.14.25, 12.0, wradadasda]` I want `OS1` How Can i get it.
In my code `second loop`also display whole array.

```
public static List readDataFromExcel() throws IOException{
        String filename = "path";

        List sheetData = new ArrayList();

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {

            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                    String value=" ";
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            value = BigDecimal.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
                            data.add(value);
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            value=cell.getStringCellValue();
                            data.add(value);
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                            value = " ".toString();
                            data.add(value);
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            value = Boolean.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue()).toString();
                            data.add(value);
                            break;
                    }

                }
                 sheetData.add(data);
                fis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return sheetData;
    }
```

Main methods

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

        List getdatafromexcel = readDataFromExcel();
        List oneserverdetailsList =null;
        for(int i =0;i<getdatafromexcel.size();i++){
            oneserverdetailsList = new ArrayList();
            oneserverdetailsList.add(getdatafromexcel.get(i));
            for(int j=0;j<oneserverdetailsList.size();j++){
                System.out.println(oneserverdetailsList.get(0));
            }

        }
```

Out Put Image - [image]

Excel File Data - [image]

Comment: You posted a lot of code and explanation, but I really do not get what you are looking for. Can you post exactly, given a defined input, what you expect it to print out? ANd in contrast to that, what your code produces.

Comment: Problem in the main method. In first loop it takes one List details. In second loop I want one element of that List. for example in first loop it take [OS1, 10.23.14.25, 12.0, wradadasda] second loop I want OS1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear I am assuming and answering your question.

You are adding a list to other list, So when you call

```
getdatafromexcel.get(i) // This will return a list
```

So, to access the element try this

```
oneserverdetailsList.get(0).get(0) //To access OS1 assuming it is in first index. Explaination : First get will return you a list and second get will return you an element.
```